# Mac doesn't connect to university Wi-Fi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I bought a MacBook recently. It connects to all other Wi-Fi and hotspot devices but it does not connect to my university Wi-Fi.

I have also done diagnostics; still does not become connected.

Comment: Have you contacted the university tech support?

Comment: does the university link show up in the list of links?

Comment: This worked for me: Go to System Preferences, Network, Advanced, DNS. Delete everything on the list(if any, if not this won’t be the soloution), restart the computer, and reconnect and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an Apple issue per se.  It's an issue with the organization's (in this case, the university's) security protocol not allowing you onto their network.

You indicate that your WiFi is functional

> it is getting connected to all other wifi and hotspot devices

It's not going to work everywhere and then suddenly stop working on one particular network.  A symptom like this points to an ***authentication issue***.

More than likely, your Uni is using an accounting and authentication mechanism like [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) (Remote Authentication Dial-In User Service). True...nobody really uses "dial in" any more, but the acronym stuck.

You need to contact your organization's IT support department to assist you in getting your device(s) authorized on their network.  Once they do this, you will be able to access the resources you are authorized to utilize.

Answer (score -1):

IF you have the choice of registering a device with your university network access setting. You can find your MAC address for specific USB ethernet adapter through advanced --> hardware and then copy that MAC address to manually register with your university network access. This is happening because of your laptop and USB adapter has different MAC address.